# glTF 2.0 Exported model from Blender not opening in Unity and 3D Viewer

Tags: materials, export, unity, gltf

20 glTF 2.0 models exported from Blender are not readable in other software. 1 isn't

This one file is the only one that doesn't work in Unity using is glTFast(Unity glTF importer) or in 3D Viewer, the default 3D model viewer on Windows 10

The issue disappears if I export without materials. That's my best clue, that it's related to materials, but my materials are following glTF guidelines in Blender's Manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html

Here is what my shader setup looks like:
[image]

the glTF is importing fine when importing it into a new blender file.

Does anybody have a clue on what's going on?

Text from glTF

```
{
"uri": "CT_Machine.gltf",
"mimeType": "model/gltf+json",
"validatorVersion": "2.0.0-dev.3.6",
"validatedAt": "2022-04-26T21:31:13.918Z",
"issues": {
    "numErrors": 8,
    "numWarnings": 0,
    "numInfos": 1,
    "numHints": 16,
    "messages": [
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/0/attributes/POSITION"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/0/attributes/NORMAL"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/0/attributes/TEXCOORD_0"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/0/indices"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/1/attributes/POSITION"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/1/attributes/NORMAL"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/1/attributes/TEXCOORD_0"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/1/indices"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/2/attributes/POSITION"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/2/attributes/NORMAL"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/2/attributes/TEXCOORD_0"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/0/primitives/2/indices"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/1/primitives/0/attributes/POSITION"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/1/primitives/0/attributes/NORMAL"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/1/primitives/0/attributes/TEXCOORD_0"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUFFER_VIEW_TARGET_MISSING",
            "message": "bufferView.target should be set for vertex or index data.",
            "severity": 3,
            "pointer": "/meshes/1/primitives/0/indices"
        },
        {
            "code": "UNUSED_OBJECT",
            "message": "This object may be unused.",
            "severity": 2,
            "pointer": "/meshes/1/primitives/0/attributes/TEXCOORD_0"
        },
        {
            "code": "IO_ERROR",
            "message": "Resource not found (CT_Machine.bin).",
            "severity": 0,
            "pointer": "/buffers/0/uri"
        },
        {
            "code": "IO_ERROR",
            "message": "Resource not found (../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_1_normal.png).",
            "severity": 0,
            "pointer": "/images/0/uri"
        },
        {
            "code": "IO_ERROR",
            "message": "Resource not found (../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_1_OcclusionRoughnessMetallic.png).",
            "severity": 0,
            "pointer": "/images/1/uri"
        },
        {
            "code": "IO_ERROR",
            "message": "Resource not found (../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_1_basecolor.png).",
            "severity": 0,
            "pointer": "/images/2/uri"
        },
        {
            "code": "IO_ERROR",
            "message": "Resource not found (../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_2_normal.png).",
            "severity": 0,
            "pointer": "/images/3/uri"
        },
        {
            "code": "IO_ERROR",
            "message": "Resource not found (../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_2_OcclusionRoughnessMetallic.png).",
            "severity": 0,
            "pointer": "/images/4/uri"
        },
        {
            "code": "IO_ERROR",
            "message": "Resource not found (../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_2_basecolor.png).",
            "severity": 0,
            "pointer": "/images/5/uri"
        },
        {
            "code": "IO_ERROR",
            "message": "Resource not found (../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/Screen_Emission.png).",
            "severity": 0,
            "pointer": "/images/6/uri"
        }
    ],
    "truncated": false
},
"info": {
    "version": "2.0",
    "generator": "Khronos glTF Blender I/O v1.7.33",
    "resources": [
        {
            "pointer": "/buffers/0",
            "mimeType": "application/gltf-buffer",
            "storage": "external",
            "uri": "CT_Machine.bin"
        },
        {
            "pointer": "/images/0",
            "storage": "external",
            "uri": "../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_1_normal.png"
        },
        {
            "pointer": "/images/1",
            "storage": "external",
            "uri": "../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_1_OcclusionRoughnessMetallic.png"
        },
        {
            "pointer": "/images/2",
            "storage": "external",
            "uri": "../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_1_basecolor.png"
        },
        {
            "pointer": "/images/3",
            "storage": "external",
            "uri": "../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_2_normal.png"
        },
        {
            "pointer": "/images/4",
            "storage": "external",
            "uri": "../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_2_OcclusionRoughnessMetallic.png"
        },
        {
            "pointer": "/images/5",
            "storage": "external",
            "uri": "../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/CT_2_basecolor.png"
        },
        {
            "pointer": "/images/6",
            "storage": "external",
            "uri": "../3D%20Objects/Hospital%20Equipment/textures/Screen_Emission.png"
        }
    ],
    "animationCount": 0,
    "materialCount": 3,
    "hasMorphTargets": false,
    "hasSkins": false,
    "hasTextures": true,
    "hasDefaultScene": true,
    "drawCallCount": 4,
    "totalVertexCount": 14980,
    "totalTriangleCount": 20348,
    "maxUVs": 1,
    "maxInfluences": 0,
    "maxAttributes": 3
}
```

}

Comment: Does the file give any errors in the glTF Validator?  https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/

Comment: Thank you. Results from glTF validator are now at the bottom of this question posted, but I don't understand the errors.

Comment: One odd thing is that the texture image names all start with the "parent folder" path `../` which might be causing some security-related issues.  The other messages here seem mostly harmless.  Are you able to post the Blender project, or a smaller sample Blender project that shows the same problem?

Comment: You can probably get rid of the IO_ERRORS by drag-and-dropping all of the related files, not just the one .gltf file.  Grab the .bin file and the .gltf file and all the textures and drop them all on the validator at once.  It needs all those different parts of the model to make sense of it all.

Comment: Originally, my textures were in a subfolder of where my model files were. Moving the textures into the same folder made all my models load normally. I would like to know if there's a proper file structure to follow for separated glTF textures and models. The validator seems to need them all uploaded at once and thus need to be part of the same folder, so I discovered a solution without finding an answer to my original question.

Comment: Drag-and-Drop knows nothing of "paths" so it may be better to validate using the command-line version or the [VSCode editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the glTF plugin.  Generally textures should work in a subfolder of the model, but asking the model to reach into parent or sibling folders for textures is disallowed in many apps.